# PageFactory initialization problems

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

i'm using Page Object model in my test automation with java selenium and i have problems in the initialization of the element using the method `PageFactory.initElements()` i have try to use the tow way in the test case class and in the constructor but is not work
 if you can see my code and help me please

EDIT:

```
@Test 
public void create(){
 POM1 ride =PageFactory.initElements(driver, POM1.class); 
 ride.create_ride();
}
```

Comment: }  
 @Test 
 public void create() {
   POM1 ride =PageFactory.initElements(driver, POM1.class);
  ride.create_ride();

 }

Comment: Please post that code in your questions, not in the comments.

Comment: Can you also include exactly what problems you are having? Your question is unclear right now.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your BasePage class (the class holding your web elements ), add this variable class and constructor:

```
public class BasePage {
  private final WebDriver driver;

  public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }
```

Then in your test class, add this WebDriver variable and initialise pagefactory after opening the browser:

```
public class Test {
private static WebDriver driver;


  public void navigateToUrl(String url) {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("75.0.3770.140").setup(); //this is only applicable if you use the webdriver manager dependency
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);
    actions = new Actions(driver);
  }
```

In subsequent methods, you can then call basePage like this:

```
basePage.username.click();
```